# How to replace characters in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, replace

I have a problem in PHP. I've a string like this:

```
"qqslsqpsq"
```

And I want to replace every `'s'` with a separated value, e.g.:

- First `'s'`  -> pos: 2 -> `'web'`
- Second `'s'` -> pos: 4 -> `'book'`
- Third `'s'`  -> pos: 7 -> `'pen'`
- ...

In the end the string will be converted to:

```
"qqweblbookqppenq"
```

I have read read `str_replace()` is powerful, but it seems that can't do that. I'm thinking of finding the position of every `'s'` and replacing it with indexes, but I can't!!

Can you guide me? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function replaceCallback() {
    static $i = 0;
    $replacements = array('web', 'book', 'pen');
    return $replacements[$i++];
}

echo preg_replace_callback('/s/',  'replaceCallback', 'ashreswfsb');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using str_replace would mean you have to looop through the string and then use the offset of the first s found to decide where and what to replace. Instead, use preg_replace, to do this in a single statement.

```
$string = 'qqslsqpsq';
$string = preg_replace('/(.*?)s(.*?)s(.*?)s/', '${1}web${2}book${3}pen', $string);
```

Comment: ops! regex again :) i should learn more about it.. seems it is more useful than i thought! let me test it amitchd... thnx